# Find all $x$ and $y$ such that $10xy^2=-x^3+4x$ and $13x^2y=-2y^3+4y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find all $x$ and $y$ such that $10xy^2=-x^3+4x$ and $13x^2y=-2y^3+4y$.

Well $(0,0)$ is a solution. And we can simplify as:

$10y^2=-x^2+4$ and $13x^2=-2y^2+4$

this is equal to:

$10y^2+x^2-4=0$ and $13x^2+2y^2-4=0$

and therefore

$10y^2+x^2-4=13x^2+2y^2-4$

which gives

$8y^2-12x^2=0$

or

$2y^2-3x^2=0$

But I feel like I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Check out the second line of your solution. You cannot cancel both sides of the equation by a variable just like that. Before that, you need to know that the variables are not $0$. Else, the effect will be like you are dividing both sides by $0$. I hope you understand now.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle10xy^2=-x^3+4x\iff x(10y^2+x^2-4)=0$

If $\displaystyle x=0,0=-2y^3+4y\iff2y(y^2-2)=0\implies y=0$ or $y^2=2$

Else $10y^2+x^2-4=0\  \ \ \ (1)$

Similarly start from $\displaystyle13x^2y=-2y^3+4y\iff y(13x^2+2y^2-4)=0$

Finally solve for $x^2,y^2$ from $(1)$ and $13x^2+2y^2-4=0$

Comment: Hm.. before I  grap my head on your method, could you explain why (where) my method is (going) wrong ?

Comment: @90intuition, clearly, you have missed some solutions. Like $x=0, y^2=2$

Comment: So I get $y=0,x=0,\pm2$ and $x=0,y=0,\pm \sqrt{2}$. And $2y^2=3x^2$ ?

Comment: @90intuition, $$2y^2=3x^2$$ is not a solution, right?

Comment: $y=\pm \sqrt\frac{3}{2}x$ , why not ? What is wrong with the reasoning in my post ?

Comment: @90intuition, expressing $y$ in terms of $x$ or the reverse can not be solutions. As you have found $$2y^2=3x^2$$ from $(1),5(3x^2)+x^2-4=\iff x^2=\frac14\iff x=?$

Comment: @90intuition I don't get it. Why can't I have a line as solution ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13458/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-90intuition)